# Automatically add types with Pyre

Tags: python, pyre-check

I'm new to Pyre and I've written some Python code using Django and have it installed in the project.

When I run `pyre`, it shows over 100 lines of type errors (missing type).

Is there a way to automatically add types to my Django code?

I don't mind having to run `pyre *some-command*`, as long as I don't have to manually add types line-by-line.

It seems like there's got to be a way, especially since Pyre knows the **exact** type of every object it complains about.

> Missing attribute annotation [4]: Attribute `is_staff` of class `UserAccount` has no type specified.

I will then add type `bool`, which raises the following error when I run `pyre` again:

> Incompatible attribute type [8]: Attribute `is_staff` declared in class `UserAccount` has type `bool` but is used as type `BooleanField[Variable[_ST](contravariant), Variable[_GT](covariant)]`

It would be nice if it just added `is_staff: BooleanField[Variable[_ST](contravariant), Variable[_GT](covariant)] = models.CharField(...)` or something similar for me.

Suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.